# Pgfplots: Weird letters on axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, plot

I am trying to plot something with pgfplots (first time using it), and for some reason there are some weird letters on the y-axis. Here is the relevant code as well as a picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = center,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
\addplot [
domain=0:0.5, 
samples=1000, 
color=red,
]
{sin(deg(x^-1))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not compile correctly:

```
./bla2.tex:16: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.16 {sin(deg(x^-1))};
```

The _fpt value stems from the fact that your domain ranges from 0:0.5, i.e. for the first point pgfplots would calculate 1/0. This raises the floating point exception which results in the value _fpt. Since pgfplots cannot identify this value as a number, it just puts it down.

A simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = center,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
\addplot [
domain=0.00001:0.5, 
samples=1000, 
color=red,
]
{sin(deg(x^-1))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.